# Django model has no foreign key object set

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

So I'm making django models of `Country` and `Embassy`, an Embassy requires two countries to be involved, one country that represents the Embassy, and another one that the Embassy is located in. So I've put two `Country`s as foreign keys in `Embassy` Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=3) #ISO Alpha-3 Country Code
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column="Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Embassy(models.Model):
    government = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="government")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="location")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column="Name")
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column="Address")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column="City")
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=-1, db_column="Phone Number")
    fax_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, db_column="Fax Number")
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column="Email")
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column="Link")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now when I go into the shell I want to find what embassies are associated with a country:

```
>>> from appName.models import Country, Embassy
>>> c = Country(code="USA", name="United States of America")
>>> c.save()
>>> Country.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Country: United States of America>]>
>>> c.embassy_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Country' object has no attribute 'embassy_set'
```

When looking over the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/) with the `Choice` model having a foreign key of the `Question` model, the question objects have an attribute that is a set of choice objects (`q.choice_set.all()` returns a QuerySet). However my `Country` objects do not have an `Embassy` object set as an attribute. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have already given a `related_name` where you have referenced the `Country` model. Also `Country` is being referenced by two fields in the `Embassy` model. With related name, you can do:

```
c.government.all()
```

This will return all `Embassy` to which the Country c is the government.

```
c.location.all()
```

Will return all `Embassy` that reside in the Country c.

Reference: [Backward relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)